# problem with android GPS provider: too many updates

Tags: android, gps, location, android-2.2-froyo, locationmanager

Although I set minTime to 10 seconds in the requestLocatioupdate method I still get new location in less than one second.

```
 public class GpsActivity extends Activity {
LocationManager mLocationManager;
TextView mTextView;
int count;
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        count = 0;
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0,mGpsLocationListener);
     } 

     Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg){
             switch(msg.what){
             case 1:
                 mTextView.setText("new location count:"+count);
             }
         }
    };

    LocationListener mGpsLocationListener = new LocationListener(){

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        count++;
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    };

}
```

My program is written for android 2.2

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a distance .if not solve,youcan see :minTime         the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.
minDistance         the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters

so i think the time not correct,if you hope update 10s,i think you should use Time andTimeTask,or handler. or you can look http://androidforums.com/developer-101/107085-proper-provider-parameter-requestlocationupdates.html